# flutter: Is there a way to align text like css "text-align-last: justify;"?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to align text both left and right in one line? like css `text-align-last: justify`

```dart
Text(
  'Hello, How are you?',
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify, // It's not aligns both left and right
)
```

[image]